# Setting Up New Machine With James Mail Server

Tags: java, email, server, smtp, james

I am moving a Java development environment from an old **Windows XP** machine to an **Apple iMac 27"** machine. The old machine has **James 2.3.1** on it and it works fine. The new machine has **James 2.3.2.1** on it and I am having trouble getting it to work.

James is being used to send emails to an Easily mail server.

I have compared both the James **config.xml** files and they are exactly the same.

---

I have marked the differences below in **BOLD**.

Eg. Old has host as **localhost** and New has host as **smtp.easily.co.uk**. Old replies to EHLO with **613bq0j**, New with **192.168.0.3**.

***Can anyone tell me where these settings might be or what causes the differences, please?***

---

**When I send an email from the old machine I get:-**

DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.s
mtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]

DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host **"localhost"**, port 25, isSSL false

220 **613bq0j SMTP Server (JAMES SMTP Server 2.3.1)** ready Wed, 13 Jul 2016 10:59:2
7 +0100 (BST)

DEBUG SMTP: connected to host **"localhost"**, port: 25

EHLO **613bq0j**

250-**613bq0j Hello 613bq0j (localhost [127.0.0.1])**

**When I send an email from the new machine I get:-**

DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=smtp; type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@4b69d0d1; class=com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport; vendor=Oracle

DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host **"smtp.easily.co.uk"**, port 25, isSSL false

220 **smtp2.easily.co.uk ESMTP** ready at Wed, 13 Jul 2016 11:22:42 +0100

DEBUG SMTP: connected to host **"smtp.easily.co.uk"**, port: 25

EHLO **192.168.0.3**

250-**smtp2.easily.co.uk Hello 192.168.0.3 [77.98.65.121]**

Comment: I have discovered that the '613bq0j' referred to above is actually the the Full Computer Name of the XP machine.

Comment: But I still have NOT worked out why Old connects to 'localhost' and New connects to 'smtp.easily.co.uk'...